# fopen in c does not work without running in debug mode

Tags: c, memory, visual-studio-2012, fopen, visual-studio-debugging

I've searched through most of the fopen questions throughout the web with no avail. I am trying to open a file with fopen. Below is a portion of my code:

```
FILE *filep = NULL;
FILE *Compilation = NULL;
printf("%s\n", fname);
char *pfname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(path) + sizeof(fname));
pfname = concat(path, fname);
printf("%s\n", pfname);
filep = fopen(pfname,"r");
if (filep == NULL){
        printf("opening file failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
printf("%p\n", filep);
```

I'm using Visual Studio express 2012 as my IDE. When I run this without debug. It crashes after printing the concatenated *pfname*. However, when I run this in debug mode, it works. *filep* does not return NULL and it will printf the memory address. I have another fopen after the printf and in debug mode it also works. Can anyone help me understand what is going on? The file is there, the permissions are right. This is newer revision of the code but previously before some untracked changes, the fopen worked. 
Thanks in advance.

---

revised code

```
FILE *filep = NULL;
FILE *Compilation = NULL;
printf("%s\n", fname);
char *pfname = (char*)malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(fname) + 1);
pfname = concat(path, fname);
printf("%s\n", pfname);
filep = fopen(pfname,"r");
if (filep == NULL){
        printf("opening file failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
printf("%p\n", filep);
char *newfile = (char*)malloc(strlen(path) + 11);
newfile = concat(path, "Result.txt");
Compilation = fopen(newfile, "a");
```

It still can't get get past fopen because it does not print the pointer.

Comment: Show us the code of `concat()`

Comment: Where do you get values for your `fname` and `path`?

Comment: `sizeof(path)` will be the size of a pointer if `path` is of type `char *`. Perhaps you meant `strlen(path) + strlen(fname) + 1`.

Comment: Your `malloc` only allocates 8 (on a 32-bit) or 16 (on a 64-bit) bytes for your pfname. It should be `malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(fname) + 1)` (allowing for zero termination).

Comment: Yes, I'm going to guess that one of your `sizeof` should be a `strlen`, possibly both

Comment: @Salgar, it has to be both. `sizeof` is the size of the data type, not the length of the string.

Comment: @mbratch if `fname` is `char fname[20];` then `sizeof(fname)` will be 20.

Comment: @mbratch I know what sizeof does, but he hasn't shown us what fname and path are, they could be fixed size arrays, in which case `sizeof` is fine.

Comment: I just tried 'malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(fname) + 1)' but it still crashes. I obtain fname and path as inputs to the function. They are both char* types.

Comment: @Salgar, indeed. Thanks. I assumed pointers since he had pointers everywhere else, but it was just an assumption which could be incorrect.

Comment: @mbratch you were correct. They are pointers. It still did not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Could you show your revised code?

Comment: Is the error different now? Does it still crash?

Comment: it still crashes. It doesn't show any errors. In debug mode it'll keep stepping through and the lines after all run fine.

Comment: I have just implemented it. This time fopen returned NULL and it is because path does not end with a \ and fname does not start with a \. To fix this, I added one extra 'strcat(pfname, "\\");' but that crashed the program again. This narrowed down the problem. I added 2 to my malloc of pfname instead of 1 at the end. thank you mbratch for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
char *pfname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(path) + sizeof(fname));
```

The `sizeof` function in C is the size of the data type. In this case, the data type is a pointer (I'm assuming). So it is 4 on a 32-bit system, or 8 on a 64-bit system. I've seen this misconception a few times here on StackOverflow.com for what `sizeof` means.

To correct it, you need:

```
char *pfname = (char*)malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(fname) + 1);
```

Because your final string (that `pfname` points to) must be the length of both strings, plus the byte to hold the zero termination.

Your existing line:

```
pfname = concat( path, file );
```

overwrites the allocated pointer that was put into `pfname`. The new file path should be computed as follows:

```
strcpy( pfname, path );   // Copy the path to the newly allocated file path buffer
strcat( pfname, file );   // Concatenate the file name to the path
```

I'm assuming `path` ends in the required directory delimeter character. Otherwise that will need to be calculated in by allocating an additional char for `pfname` and concatenating a `\`.

The same logic will apply to your subsequent file logic for Compilation.

Comment: I have just implemented it. This time fopen returned NULL and it is because path does not end with a \ and fname does not start with a \. To fix this, I added one extra 'strcat(pfname, "\\");' but that crashed the program again. This narrowed down the problem. I added 2 to my malloc of pfname instead of 1 at the end. thank you mbratch for the help

Comment: Now the code actually stops at the if-statment of 'if((filep == NULL){' It breakpoints to malloc.c at the line of 'res = _heap_alloc(size)'

Comment: @user2127579 Here I just did a revision. Compare this with what you have: http://codepad.org/JMYUZ7m1.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sizeof()` to determin the needed space for `pfname` is wrong I guess. I should have the declarations of `path` and `fname` to be sure but either they are pointers, then you would get the pointer size (4 or 8) or they are arrays, then you would get the complete array size. Use `malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(fname)+1)` instead.